# select childenode from collection htmlagilitypack

Tags: .net, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

i have this hap code of which tries to selects sub-node from the main collection of nodes

```
Dim items As HtmlNodeCollection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//channel/item")

 For Each item In items
   link = item.SelectSingleNode("//link")
   title = item.SelectSingleNode("//title")
 next
```

the xml is

```
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
    <title>title title</title>
<link>http://www.link.com</link>
<description>long decription</description>
<item>
    <title>title title</title>
    <link>http://www.link.com/</link>
    <description> description</description>
    </item>
    <item>
    <title>title title</title>
    <link>http://www.link.com/</link>
    <description> description</description>
    </item>
    <item>
    <title>title title</title>
    <link>http://www.link.com/</link>
    <description> description</description>
    </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

but i don get the appropriate node title and link under item for each of the items.
where am i getting it wrong?

i could have just done

```
Dim links As HtmlNodeCollection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//channel/item/link")
Dim titles As HtmlNodeCollection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//channel/item/title")
```

but i need the link and title for each item

Comment: Why don't you include some HTML in your post so we can see what you are querying against?

Comment: Are the `item` tags not closed in your example?

Comment: @thecoon they are, it was a typo error, thanks for that. i corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me like a bug in HtmlAgilityPack. I had issues only retrieving the `InnerText` for the `link` element, not the others. For that one, the text was found as its sibling, not as child at least.

Anyway, this wouldn't be the first bug encountered in HtmlAgilityPack, so we should live with it :).

**Alternative:**

Use an `XmlDocument` since there's no HTML involved here. That is an XML.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(ConsoleApplication3.Properties.Settings.Default.RSS);

    var items = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//channel/item");
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        XmlNode node = (XmlNode)item;
        var link = node.SelectSingleNode("//link");
        var title = node.SelectSingleNode("//title");

        if (link != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(link.InnerText);
        }
        if (title != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(title.InnerText);
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output:**

> http://www.link.com
>
> title title
>
> http://www.link.com
>
> title title
>
> http://www.link.com
>
> title title

Comment: please look at the xml again, i thin item is a direct descendant